# Element-wise XOR in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, logic, xor

I know that logical AND is &, and logical OR is | in a Pandas Series, but I was looking for an element-wise logical XOR. I could express it in terms of AND and OR, I suppose, but I'd prefer to use an XOR if one is available.

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python XOR: `a ^ b`

[Numpy logical XOR](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_xor.html): `np.logical_xor(a,b)`

Testing performance - result are equal:

**1. Sequence of random booleans with size 10000**

```
In [7]: a = np.random.choice([True, False], size=10000)
In [8]: b = np.random.choice([True, False], size=10000)

In [9]: %timeit a ^ b
The slowest run took 7.61 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 11 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.logical_xor(a,b)
The slowest run took 6.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 11 us per loop
```

**2. Sequence of random booleans with size 1000**

```
In [11]: a = np.random.choice([True, False], size=1000)
In [12]: b = np.random.choice([True, False], size=1000)

In [13]: %timeit a ^ b
The slowest run took 21.52 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 us per loop

In [14]: %timeit np.logical_xor(a,b)
The slowest run took 19.45 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 us per loop
```

**3. Sequence of random booleans with size 100**

```
In [15]: a = np.random.choice([True, False], size=100)
In [16]: b = np.random.choice([True, False], size=100)

In [17]: %timeit a ^ b
The slowest run took 33.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 614 ns per loop

In [18]: %timeit np.logical_xor(a,b)
The slowest run took 45.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 616 ns per loop
```

**4. Sequence of random booleans with size 10**

```
In [19]: a = np.random.choice([True, False], size=10)
In [20]: b = np.random.choice([True, False], size=10)

In [21]: %timeit a ^ b
The slowest run took 86.10 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 509 ns per loop

In [22]: %timeit np.logical_xor(a,b)
The slowest run took 40.94 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 511 ns per loop
```

Comment: python xor operator ^ is overloaded by numpy library to carry out numpy.logical_xor internally. So readers should note that the performance testing results are equal for these, because these are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that `a^b` and `np.logical_xor(a,b)` are *not* equivalent that really tripped me up but was a simple fix in the end.  Hopefully this saves someone else the headache.

I recently upgraded from Pandas 0.25.3 to 2.0.3 (and numpy from 1.19.0 to 1.24.4) which raised the issue.

Let `a` be a `DataFrame` of `bool` that has duplicates on the `Index`.
Let `b` be a `Series` also of `bool`, where `b.index == a.columns`.

My intent was to broadcast `b` to `a`, and take the element-wise xor of every row of `a` and `b`, where any duplicates on `a.index` should just be passed on to the output.

This code worked on my old setup...

```
np.logical_xor(a,b.to_frame().T)
```

...but failed on my new setup:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'
```

I believe because something about the broadcasting was attempting to concat `b` (`b.index` being a meaningless `[0]`) onto `a` (with index of Timestamps) I believe to sort it to make it monotonic.

The solution was, as this OP led me to consider:

```
a^b
```

The aggravating/wonderful thing is that this also appears to work on my old pandas/numpy "production" setup.  Coincidentally this was the first time I ever used "git blame".  Answer: "Initial commit" 3 years ago , so either `a^b` didn't work in an even older version of Pandas or I didn't know about it.